# How do I encode binary file data to ISO-8859-1 to attach to the body of an HTTP post message

Tags: c++, windows, http-post, libcurl, iso-8859-1

I'm trying to convert the full string of bytes from a file opened in binary mode to a string encoded in the ISO-8859-1 character set.  My understanding is that by converting to ISO-8859-1 all binary information from the file is retained which is why it is being converted to that format.  Is this a valid statement?

I'm working in C++ (Visual Studio 2017) building an executable to be used on the Windows platform.  I'm not experienced in HTTP programming.

I have prototype code written in PowerShell code which successfully performs the functionality that I'm trying to duplicate in C++.  In the power shell code an HTTP message is sent to upload a firmware file to a device.

- The message includes headers and a body:
- The message is using the multipart/form-data protocol.

An example of the headers of the message are:

```
Authorization: Bearer Yosda0IDRQuVaU_L0SnV5g==                                                                                                              
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=42b745c8-4da8-454e-8c13-cbb5c1f7694f                                                                           
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

An example of the body of the message is:

```
--1a2fc07a-d882-4470-a1da-79716d34cd9b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upgrade_file"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

// File data (encoded in ISO-8859-1 format) goes here //
--1a2fc07a-d882-4470-a1da-79716d34cd9b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"

Install OS
--1a2fc07a-d882-4470-a1da-79716d34cd9b--
```

The PowerShell script is converting the file with the following lines of code:

```
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file.FullName);
if ( $bytes )
{
  $enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(iso-8859-1);
  $data = $enc.GetString($bytes);
}
```

Once the headers and body are setup the message is sent and the firmware is uploaded when running the PowerShell code.

In my C++ code I've got the headers and the pre-body and post-body codes worked out.  I think (not sure) that I just need to convert the file to iso-8859-1 to get the message to work now.

I'm using libcurl to send the message.

```
res = curl_easy_perform(pCurl);
```

Currently (without converting file to iso-8859-1) I get the following error message from the function call:

> Failure when receiving data from the peer

When the message is sent I can see that only some bytes are uploaded.  I assume that could be because the file data is not properly encoded and when it is reading that data it reaches some point where the data is in a format that it cannot handle.

Comment: You are not supposed to encode the binary file data AT ALL, you are supposed to send its raw bytes AS-IS, that is what `application/octet-stream` does. When using libcurl, you should be using [`curl_mime_init()`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_mime_init.html), [`curl_mime_addpart()`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_mime_addpart.html), [`curl_mime_filedata()`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_mime_filedata.html), etc to prepare a `multipart/form-data` request, and then send it using [`CURLOPT_MIMEPOST`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_MIMEPOST.html)...

Comment: ... even the older [`CURLOPT_HTTPPOST`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPPOST.html) can post a binary file in `multipart/form-data` format via [`curl_formadd(CURLFORM_FILE)`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_formadd.html).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I thought it was a bit weird to change from binary to ISO-8859-1 but as I indicated I'm not an experienced HTTP programmer.  I was just following the PowerShell script that I was given and that's what it appeared to be doing.  Before seeing your reply I had converted over to using the 'mime' functions and it almost worked.  I just posted another question on this forum that perhaps you could provide an answer for.  The upload appears to start okay but does not complete the entire file.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I posted an answer to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55409192/).